# determine if the system is time-invariant

Tags: systems-theory

I need to determine if the following system is time-invariant or not, and I'm a bit unsure about it.
$$y(t)= \int_{-\infty}^{t-2} \tau \cdot x(2\tau)d\tau $$

Comment: Have you checked if $y(t+\delta t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t- 2} \tau\cdot x(2\tau + \delta t)d\tau$?

Comment: @copper.hat Hmm it is? How so?

Comment: I don't think so? The system is time-invariant if you can compute $y(t+\delta t)$ by replacing $x(s)$ by $x(s+\delta t)$ at every point in the calculation of $y(t)$

Comment: @copper.hat $x'(2a) = x(2a+\delta t)$... $\delta t$ has no dependence on $a$.

Comment: @copper.hat A system $y(x(s), t)$ is time-invariant if, for every shift $\delta t\in \mathbb{R}$, $$y(x(s+\delta t), t) = y(x(s), t+\delta t).$$

Comment: @user7530: I am removing my embarrassing comments above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is *not* time-invariant. Consider the response to the input signal $x_1(t)=x(t-t_0)$:

$$y_1(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t-2}\tau x_1(2\tau)d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^{t-2}\tau x(2\tau-t_0)d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^{t-2-t_0/2}(\tau+t_0/2) x(2\tau)d\tau \neq y(t-t_0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1_{ [0,2] }$, then for $t > 100$, we have $y_{x}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{98} \tau  1_{ [0,2] }(2 \tau) d \tau = \int_0^1 \tau d \tau = {1 \over 2}$.

If we let $x' = 1_{ [2,4] } $ (note that $x'(t) = x(t-2)$), then $y_{x'}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{98} \tau  1_{ [2,4] }(2 \tau) d \tau = \int_1^2 \tau d \tau = {3 \over 2}$.

Hence the system is not time invariant.

If it was, we would have $y_{x'}(t) = y_x (t-2)$.